# What you said about her is nothing else than salander

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, usage

What you said about her is nothing else than salander. 
Correct it where necessary? 
Find the error.

Comment: Identical question asked on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

The word *slander* is misspelled. And *nothing **else than** slander* is nonidiomatic; I would say *nothing **but** slander.*

Comment: "nothing less than slander" would also be idiomatic.

Comment: @Jasper Or "nothing other than slander".